# Insert Hierarchical numbering to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

How to allow user to insert hierarchical numbering like below. As for now, i'm using textbox and user will enter the number such as `1, 1.1, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1`. And I can only display the data plainly, with no indent. I'm using PHP and MySql as database.

```
 1 List item
   1.1 List item
     1.1.1 List item
 2 List item
   2.1 List item
     2.1.1 List item
```

My form.

```
<form action="basicview.php?id=<?php echo $p_aid; ?>&&do=insert" method="post">             
                <div style="padding-bottom:5px">
                    <div style="float:left;width:5%;padding-top:7px"><label style="color:blue">No</label></div>
                    <div style="float:left;"><input class="text-input" type="text" name="t_no" size="10" value="" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-bottom:5px">
                    <div style="float:left;width:15%;padding-top:7px"><label style="color:blue">Deliverables</label></div>
                    <div style="float:left;"><textarea class="text-input textarea" name="t_deliverables" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

PHP.

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'insert')
{   
    $t_no           = $_POST['t_no'];
    $t_deliverables = $_POST['t_deliverables']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_detail (p_aid,t_no,t_deliverables) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ($p_aid,'$t_no','$t_deliverables')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    redirect("basicview.php?id=$p_aid&type=success&msg=new+row+added");
}
```

Comment: please provide more info. may you post your form?

Comment: @Ormoz i put the code in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Your question is not very clear tell you, explain little bit more if you dont mind. i mean that portion heirechly one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the users be able to post html data rather than plain text, you may use `ckeditor` or other similar tools. these tools convert textarea to a box like this one in stackoverflow.

But bear in mind that to prevent XSS attacks, you must verify posted data in server-side.

More importantly, the way you have scribed your sql query, it is highly vulnerable to `sql injection`. use `prepared statements` instead. For example if a malicious user post these data, you lose all data in the tbl_detail table:

$_POST['t_no']="1"

$_POST['t_deliverables']="1'); drop table tbl_detail;--"